# Child Component doesn't render data passed from Parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have  child component, inside the render function I am populating a view like this

```
{this.state.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children.map(
                        (metadata: SupportTopicMetadataTreeNode) => (
                            <div>
                                <SupportTopicMetadataContainer
                                    supportTopicMetadataTreeNode={metadata}
                                ></SupportTopicMetadataContainer>

                            </div>
                        )
  )}
```

Which is type of `SupportTopicMetadataTreeNode` Like below:

```
export default class SupportTopicMetadataTreeNode {
    public data: SupportTopicMetadata;
    public children: SupportTopicMetadataTreeNode[];
}
```

In Parent Component I am calling above Component like below:

```
 {this.state.metadataList && this.state.metadataList.map((metadata: SupportTopicMetadataTreeNode) =>
                    <div>
                        <SupportTopicMetadataContainer supportTopicMetadataTreeNode={metadata}>
                        </SupportTopicMetadataContainer>
                    </div>

                )}
```

Before calling Child function above I am setting state with my current modified value to `metadaList` like this:

```
this.setState({ metadataList: filteredList });
```

But in child component it doesn't populate with valid data that is `filteredList`. I have checked that state is correctly assigned my expected value to `metadataList` Not getting what the problem is?

I am also trying to pass `filteredList` to child component so that can loop directly on `this.state.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children`

Any idea how to pass that to child state or variable that defined on child state?

**`Update:`**

I have initialize the constructor like below:

```
constructor(props: ISupportTopicMetadataEntryContainerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            supportTopicMetadataTreeNode: props.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode,


        };

    }
```

So I need not to call like this `this.props.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children` as answered like this. Now I can get that `this.state.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children`. Don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React | pass data from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952882/react-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component)

Comment: Not really, my issue is different totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was using incorrect data of your component. In your child component `SupportTopicMetadataContainer`, `supportTopicMetadataTreeNode` is props,  not state like you're using `this.state.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children`.

It should be `this.props.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children`, that'll fix your issue.

Comment: I have tried that but the data in `filteredList.children` and  `this.props.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children` are different that's why I am here... not getting the clue, even I got some `[]` empty array on `this.props.supportTopicMetadataTreeNode.children` when its passed to `SupportTopicMetadataContainer` component

Comment: Could you show the whole component code or some kinds of all process? You could put it to codesandbox or update in the question, it would help a lot to understand what issue you got

Comment: Its a big component very tough to include here in question as well sandbox. I am trying on codesandbox.

Comment: Just the main part, no need whole project

Comment: Yes am talking about  a single component, trying it.