# React, pass function as prop in different component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-btrcsn?file=Products.tsx)

I have a simple list of products and a cart that I would like to add the products to.

The `Products` and `Cart` are separate components in the index file.

I have the function to add the products to the cart in the Products components but how do I pass this to the Cart component that is outside the Products component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Products from "./Products";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Products />
      <Cart />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a common items variable and a function addItems in App.tsx and you need to pass this function as prop to Product component which when adds a product will call this same function in App.tsx file and update the items list.And this items list can be passed to the Cart component.
Here check this live demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qq5cea?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 2):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-txpsds

```js
// index.tsx
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import { CartProvider } from "./context";
import Products from "./Products";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <div>
        <Products />
        <Cart />
      </div>
    </CartProvider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```js
// Products.tsx
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AddCartContext } from "./context";
import { IProduct } from "./interface";
const Products = () => {
  const addItems = useContext(AddCartContext);

  const items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Product One",
      price: 20
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Product Two",
      price: 56
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Product Three",
      price: 13
    }
  ];

  const handleClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>,
    item: IProduct
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addItems(item);
  };

  const listItems = items.map(item => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      {`${item.name}: £${item.price}`}
      <input type="submit" value="+" onClick={e => handleClick(e, item)} />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Products</h2>
        {listItems}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

```js
const Cart = () => {
  const items = useContext(CartContext);
  const cartItems = items.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>{`${item.name}: £${item.price}`}</div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cart</h2>
      {cartItems}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
// context.tsx
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext([]);
export const AddCartContext = createContext(item => {});

export function CartProvider(props) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const itemsRef = useRef(items);
  itemsRef.current = items;

  return (
    <AddCartContext.Provider
      value={useCallback(item => {
        setItems([...itemsRef.current, item]);
      }, [])}
    >
      <CartContext.Provider value={items}>
        {props.children}
      </CartContext.Provider>
    </AddCartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share a `property` or `function` between multiple `components` you need to put that `property` or `function` in closest `parent` of those `components` so you can pass them as `props`.

In your case try to add your `function` to your `App` Component and then pass the function to both `Products` and `Cart` Components

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 work-arounds for your problem.

1. You can make the `Cart` component as the child component of Products through which you can pass the `addToCart()` as Props to Cart. [but it is not meaningful]
2. You can bring the `state` from Product Component to `App` i.e make the `App` as a stateful component and for `products and Cart`, make them as statelesss. Pass the data and methods as props.

For the second option, check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953085/12210002).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the react docs for [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Move your `cart` state up into the closest common ancestor - `App`.

From `App`, pass `cart` and `setCart` as props into both `Products` and `Cart` as needed.

```
import React, { useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IProduct {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

const App = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<IProduct[]>([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Products cart={cart} setCart={setCart} />
      <Cart cart={cart} />
    </div>
  );
};

function Cart({ cart = [] }: { cart: IProduct[] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cart</h2>
      {cart.map(item => (
        <div>{`${item.name}: £${item.price}`}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Products({
  cart,
  setCart
}: {
  cart: IProduct[];
  setCart: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IProduct[]>>;
}) {
    const items: IProduct[] = [{id: 1,name: "Product One",price: 20},{id: 2,name: "Product Two",price: 56},{id: 3,name: "Product Three",price: 13}];

  const handleClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>,
    item: IProduct
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Products</h2>
        {items.map(item => (
          <div>
            {`${item.name}: £${item.price}`}
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="+"
              onClick={e => setCart([...cart, item])}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zknhs1?file=interface.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I improved your code a little, the main thing that needed to be done was to move the state to a higher level

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-iicy7v?file=Shop.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Shop Products={Products} Cart={Cart} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

move logic to Shop:

```
const Shop = ({ Products, Cart }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (item: IProduct) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (item: IProduct) => {
    const itemWillBeRemoved = cart.find(e => e.id === item.id);
    const index = cart.indexOf(itemWillBeRemoved);
    const newCart = [...cart];
    newCart.splice(index, 1);
    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Product One",
      price: 20
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Product Two",
      price: 56
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Product Three",
      price: 13
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Products items={items} addToCart={addToCart} />
      <Cart items={cart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**But the best way  - use State Management**

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/)
[image: Redix]